# Howto put son_decode array straight into function?

Tags: php, json, function, warnings

What am i missing, also tried to give the functions arguments and inserted $poolstale_enc_json but this also gives errors  ?

```
$poolstale_get_json = file_get_contents('../scripts/PoolStale');
$poolstale_enc_json = json_decode($poolstale_get_json);
$poolstale_enc_val = array();
$poolstale_enc_date = array();

function get_val_value(){
    foreach($poolstale_enc_json as $tmp){
        array_push($poolstale_enc_val,$tmp[1]); 
//      print_r($poolstale_enc_val); echo "</br>";      
    }
    return $poolstale_enc_val;
}

function get_val_date(){
    foreach($poolstale_enc_json as $tmp){
        array_push($poolstale_enc_date,$tmp[2]);
    // print_r($poolstale_enc_date); echo "</br>";  
    }
    return $poolstale_enc_date;
}

get_val_date();
```

The errors are:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: poolstale_enc_json in /opt/lampp/htdocs/scripts/chart-data.php on line 90

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/scripts/chart-data.php on line 90

Notice: Undefined variable: poolstale_enc_date in /opt/lampp/htdocs/scripts/chart-data.php on line 94
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a basic scope issue. `get_val_date()` doesn't have access to `$poolstale_enc_json` because it is out of scope. You just need to pass it as a parameter to the function to solve this issue.

```
get_val_date() {
```

should become

```
function get_val_date($poolstale_enc_json){
```

Comment: ok I'll try it again because i already did this but i think i'm a little sleepy ;-) thanks for responding

Comment: $poolstale_enc_val = array();
$poolstale_enc_date = array(); Those have tobe inside the function was the solution